# "Embedded statement cannot be declaration" error in Genie

Tags: genie

It seems that is something out-of-date in Genie's website. Perhaps HashMaps are not supported anymore or their syntax has changed.

If one tries the examples from the old BarryK [website](http://barryk.org/genie/gee.htm):

```
uses
    Gee

init
    var d = new dict of string,string
    d["fruit"] = "apple"
    d["animal"] = "dog"
    d.set("plant","cactus")
    d.set("animal","hippopotomus") /*changes from 'dog'*/
    if d.contains("plant") == true do print "Key 'plant' is in dictionary"
    print "%s", d.get("animal")
    for o in d.keys do print o //old libgee use d.get_keys()
    for o in d.values do print o //old libgee use d.get_values()
    d.remove("animal")
```

One gets the error `dicts.gs:7.36-7.40: error: syntax error, embedded statement cannot be declaration` for the lines starting with:

- if d.contains
- for o in d.keys
- for o in d.values

Furthermore, using the official Genie [website](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Genie#Dicts_.28HashMap.29) there is no much success:

```
[indent=4]

uses
    Gee

init

    /* test dicts */
    var d = new dict of string,string

    /* add or change entries with following */
    d["Genie"] = "Great"
    d["Vala"] = "Rocks"


    /* access entires using d[key] */
    /* note that instead of "d.get_keys ()" it is "d.keys" in newer Versions of Gee */
    for s in d.get_keys ()
        print "%s => %s", s, d[s]
```

Generates the error: `` dicts.gs:18.14-18.23: error: The name `get_keys' does not exist in the context of `Gee.HashMap<string,string>' `` for line `for s in d.get_keys ()`

Am I missing something or is the site out of date?

**Update** For completness, I've been using Manjaro linux, my libgee package is version 0.18 and there is an extra error in compilation `gee-0.8.vapi:664.4-664.13: warning: [Deprecated] is deprecated. Use [Version (deprecated = true, deprecated_since = "", replacement = "")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "embedded statement cannot be declaration" message is caused by using the `do` keyword instead of starting a new block. If you use:

```
if d.contains("plant") == true
    print "Key 'plant' is in dictionary"
```

This will compile. Alternatively you can change `print` from a statement to a function call and that will also compile:

```
if d.contains("plant") == true do print( "Key 'plant' is in dictionary" )
```

A working example, also updated for Gee version 0.8, would be:

```
[indent=4]
uses
    Gee

init
    var d = new dict of string,string
    d["fruit"] = "apple"
    d["animal"] = "dog"
    d.set("plant","cactus")
    d.set("animal","hippopotomus") /*changes from 'dog'*/
    if d.has_key("plant") == true do print( "Key 'plant' is in dictionary" )
    print "%s", d.get("animal")
    for o in d.keys do print( o )
    for o in d.values do print( o )
    d.unset("animal")
```

I wasn't aware of a difference between the `print` statement and the `print` function call, but you seem to have found one. I guess the parser is looking to `do` an action and an action should be a function call.

For the example from the Genie tutorial you have missed the comment 'note that instead of "d.get_keys ()" it is "d.keys" in newer Versions of Gee'. Gee 0.8 is actually the newer version, so you should be using `for s in d.keys`. I have updated the tutorial to just show the newer version because Gee 0.8 has been around for a long time now. The working example is:

```
[indent=4]
uses
    Gee

init
    /* test dicts */
    var d = new dict of string,string

    /* add or change entries with following */
    d["Genie"] = "Great"
    d["Vala"] = "Rocks"

    /* access entires using d[key] */
    for var s in d.keys
        print "%s => %s", s, d[s]
```

The compiler warning about the `[Deprecated]` attribute being deprecated is because Vala 0.32 replaced it with the `[Version]` attribute and the Gee bindings have not been updated yet.